# initramfs: where can I determine what goes into /sbin?

Tags: boot, initramfs

Where can I configure which binaries **update-initramfs** copies into the **/sbin** directory inside the initrd image?

I have been looking under /etc/initramfs-tools and /usr/lib/initramfs-tools but couldn't find the list of binaries anywhere

```
# grep -ri sbin /etc/initramfs-tools
# grep -ri sbin /usr/lib/initramfs-tools
#
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the entries in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks`. These files are executed when you type `update-initramfs`. Create your own hook script or remove scripts.

Another folder is `/etc/initramfs-tools/hook`

From `man initramfs-tools`

```
   Hooks can be found in two places: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks  and
   /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks.  They are executed during generation of the
   initramfs-image and are responsible for  including  all  the  necessary
   components  in the image itself. No guarantees are made as to the order
   in which the different scripts are  executed  unless  the  prereqs  are
   setup in the script.
```

Note, the hook-scripts are part of the packages, e.g. `kmod`. The package creates the file `kmod` in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks`.

---

*Sample script*

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# Copy the compatibility symlinks until initramfs-tools will be converted
# to use the kmod program.

if [ "$1" = "prereqs" ]; then exit 0; fi

. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions

copy_exec /bin/kmod
cp -a /sbin/modprobe /sbin/rmmod $DESTDIR/sbin/

mkdir -p $DESTDIR/lib/modprobe.d/
if [ "$(echo /lib/modprobe.d/*)" != "/lib/modprobe.d/*" ]; then
  cp -a /lib/modprobe.d/* $DESTDIR/lib/modprobe.d/
fi
```

As you can see, the hook-script copies all files in `/lib/modprobe.d/` into `initramfs/lib/modprobe.d/`

```
cp -a /lib/modprobe.d/* $DESTDIR/lib/modprobe.d/
```

and `modprobe` into `initramfs/sbin`

```
cp -a /sbin/modprobe /sbin/rmmod $DESTDIR/sbin/
```

---

Your own `initrd.img` with one file `foo`

```
cd 
mkdir initrd
cd initrd
touch foo   # an example file
find . | cpio -o -H newc > ../initrd.img
cd ..
gzip initrd.img
cp initrd.img.gz initrd.img
```

Check the content of your `initrd.img`

```
cd
mkdir initrd_out
cd initrd_out
cpio -i < ../initrd.img
```

And with `ls` you should see one file

```
% ls
foo
```

Comment: Thank you! I also found a directory for hooks in /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks, I might try placing my own hook there instead?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Is removing scripts the "correct" thing to do? Is there any way to create an override? I notice that the hooks are set `+x` so I can just remove that to disable them, but a package update might re-enable them.